# using as3svgrendererlib in flash cs 5.5

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, svg

I am trying to use http://code.google.com/p/as3svgrendererlib/ in my flash cs 5.5 project to import and load svg files.

I downloaded the swc file from http://code.google.com/p/as3svgrendererlib/downloads/list and linked it in actionscript settings.

I tried compiling the project using the following code:

```
package { 
    import flash.display.Sprite; 
    import flash.display.DisplayObject; 
    import flash.events.Event; 

    public class Main extends Sprite { 
        import flash.net.URLLoader; 
        import flash.net.URLRequest; 
        //ProcessExecutor.instance.initialize(stage);

        public function Main():void { 
            if (stage) init(); 
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init); 
        } 

        private function init(e:Event = null):void { 
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init); 
            // entry point 
            var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(); 
            myLoader.dataFormat = "text"; 
            myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, xmlComplete, false, 0, true); 
            myLoader.load( new URLRequest("assets/spring_tree_final.svg")); 
        } 


        public function xmlComplete(e:Event):void { 
            trace("it's finished loading"); 
            var svg:SVGDocument = new SVGDocument();
            svg.parse(e.target.data);
            addChild(svg); 
            stage.addChild(svg); 
        } 

    } 

}
```

But I kept getting the following error:

- C:\Users\xx\Desktop\load_svg\Main.as, Line 33    1046: Type was not
  found or was not a compile-time constant: SVGDocument.
- C:\Users\xx\Desktop\load_svg\Main.as, Line 33    1180: Call to a
  possibly undefined method SVGDocument.

So i checked out the source from http://code.google.com/p/as3svgrendererlib/source/checkout and tried importing it using the following line:

```
import com.lorentz.SVG.*;
```

right below the 'import flash.events.Event' line.

But I continue to receive the same errors as before.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need this import statement:

```
 import com.lorentz.SVG.display.SVGDocument;
```

Comment: Should the program load that direction automatically.

Comment: That actually worked! thanks. I thought using .* meant all the classes would be imported automatically.

Comment: @V-A It does, but it's not recursive. So with your import, classes under c.l.SVG would be imported, but not anything under a subfolder of SVG